# Defining optimal varchar length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I have found that there is no difference  between **varchar(20)** and **varchar(40)** in sense of performance.

But then I asked myself logically question, why don't create a table where all character columns will be **varchar(4000)**?

In my opinion, I think there exists some distinction between **varchar(3)** and **varchar(4000)** if my column contains only 3 character. But I can't find that distinction.

Comment: You can protect your table this way if you don't wanna to overflood your column if there would be wrong insert or something

Comment: That would be some kind of security aspect, but I think there would be more.

Comment: There is a distinction.  One allows values up to 3 characters the other up to 4,000.  That is pretty much the only significant difference between the two.  And why not use `8000` instead of `4000`?  That is the "maximum" value for `varchar` before `max`.

Comment: In last sentence I wrote example where my column contains only 3 character, and whether would be distinction if I put varchar (8000) instead varchar(3)

Comment: If I recall right there shouldn't be any performance or storage differences between any varchar(n) for n 1 to 8000, but varchar(max) is a different case as memory is handled in a different fashion for max, with performance implications.

Comment: For one thing: anything larger than 900 bytes **CANNOT** be indexed!

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in storage space just like defined in documentation from Microsoft.

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n
>   defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max
>   indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The
>   storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The
>   ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

The difference that you have is a potential for bad data. Columns should be defined to allow maximum valid input not just allow anything. I have seen `VARCHAR(MAX)` columns that resulted in blowing up database because someone ran bad update statement and filled up every row with almost 2 GB worth of data.

Run the following query and look at the execution plan.

```
DECLARE @tableOne TABLE
(
 id INT
,MySmallField VARCHAR(3)
)

DECLARE @tabletwo TABLE
(
 id INT
,MyBigField VARCHAR(3000)
)

INSERT INTO @tableOne
VALUES( 0, 'aaa' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 5, 'ddd' )

INSERT INTO @tableTwo
VALUES( 0, 'aaa' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 1, 'aaa' ),( 2, 'aaa' ),( 3, 'bbb' ),( 4, 'ccc' ),( 5, 'ddd' ),( 5, 'ddd' )


SELECT * FROM @tableOne WHERE MySmallField = 'ccc'

SELECT * FROM @tabletwo WHERE MyBigField = 'ccc'
```

Download [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) it is free tool that gives you interface that is more easy to work with than SSMS.

Looking at execution plan for a simple statement you will see that for insert into large column sql server added `Compute Scalar` function that does the following

```
Expr1104=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(3000),[Union1103],0
```

For this operation data site rose from `784 B` to `74 KB`. This was done with only 50 rows insert. The bigger the operation the large impact of this will be.

Comment: Is there any impact on performance when comparing two columns, let's say varchar (3) and varchar(3000) where both columns contains 3 or less characters. How SQL treat those columns, as different or as same? Did it convert one type into another?

Comment: run a explain on this query and see the cost ! and then try to compare  varchar(3) with a varchar(3) and see the results

Comment: When you have larger column SQL Server with estimate Data Size to be bigger than it is actually is, making it think it is more costly.

Comment: Varchar(1-4000) will store the field with the rest of the record on a database page. Varchar(max) will store the field data elsewhere and only keep a pointer to the field with the record data. Due to the extra read of the pointer there is a performance penalty for varchar(max) vs. varchar(1-4000).

Comment: @Brad_Z In [tag:sql-server] `varchar` is stored as row data if it is `1-8000`. `VARCHAR(max)` is treaded as LOB. I'm not sure how you derived that I said that performance is the same.

Comment: Not saying you did. Just adding some depth on the methods SQL Server uses to store varchar(max) data. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It will not make a difference from storage stand point. 
It will only affect you sort performance if you rows are `filled-up` as it will spill to `tempdb` **OR** if your col size `varchar` columns are declared as 5000 bytes but actually have contents much less than that your query will be allocated memory that it doesn't require which is obviously inefficient and can lead to waits for memory grants.
 *A good approach is to choose a maximum length value that is reasonable according to the actual data to be stored.*

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "because you're reserving more memory than you need". Really, why stop at `varchar` size? Why not use a single big `varbinary` column for everything? Or `xml`? Why not have all the columns nullable? Why use constraints and foreign keys? The benefit of a schema is exactly that - you have some schema you can rely on. It has its own deficiencies, of course (less flexibility, of course), but that's why this is not the only method of storing data (for example, document databases often don't require a schema at all, which offers more flexibility and doesn't require you to declare your intent twice).

The performance aspect is much more complicated. There's a given page size SQL server uses to store data. That limits you to 8060 B of data per page. Splitting data across pages happens transparently, but it carries a performance penalty. Limiting your maximum row size allows you to judge performance better. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx says a bit more about the page size issues.

Even more importantly, the length gets back to bite you when considering indices. An index on `varchar(3)` is just fine. `varchar(4000)` is just ridiculous. It's going to hurt your performance on lookups and inserts alike, and you really don't want that.

Sparse columns complicate things further. It's also convenient to have a reasonable size on stored procedure (and query) parameters. All those things tend to prevent you from making silly mistakes, not to mention that they help against trolls entering unreasonable data :)

In the end, the idea is "give the engine as much information as possible to make sure you're getting the performance you need".

Comment: You are not reserving memory in this way. It doesn't take up more room on the page to simple say, "I could have more characters here." See the other answer for more on the variable nature of VARCHAR.

Comment: @KarlKieninger I wasn't talking about needing more space. I was talking about declaring intent. Intent is very important, since you want your ideas to be as clear as possible to have a maintainable application.

Comment: Fair. From that standpoint , yes absolutely. Also, it is a good defensive programming technique to prevent runaway data from being stashed in necessarily large fields.

Answer (score 0):

> As some users has explained VARCHAR(10) will have the same
>   performance as VARCHAR(1000), I think this is not entirely true.
>
> VARCHAR(10) means you can store UPTO 10 character in that field. 
>   VARCHAR(1000) means you can store upto 1000 characters in that field.
>
> Now if sql server has to pull data from table which has a column with
>   datatype VARCHAR(1000) but has only 10 charaters long string stored in
>   it. Yes in this case the performance will be the same as if would have
>   been a VARCHAR(10) Column.
>
> But to say VARCHAR(1000) will have same performance as VARCHAR(10) even if VARCHAR(1000) has a lot more than 10 characters stored in it.
>   it isn’t true at all.  I see these allowed character lengths as more of
>   a constraints to stop garbage data from coming in.